# I need a JS based app launcher that can launch any third party web apps

Tags: web-apps, javascript

I am looking for a JavaScript based utility which is suitable to launch third party apps. Following are the features expected:

1. Launch the app via URL which can be loaded in iFrame when App is not interacting with the main application
2. Launch the app in a popup on the page itself and it can interact with the main application in background.

Any reference will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

[Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) might help. You can easily control the desired web app in-front via scraping what you need, or in the background via headless.